# deleting 0d carriage return from .csv file

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep

working with a script I've got this issue, most of the times 
when I run the script this is the output file I've got:

```
device_id,ip_address,serial_number
 SEP0c1167231746, 148.000.000.32
 SEP0c1167223fa5, 148.000.000.30
 SEP0c1167224170, 148.000.000.30
 SEP0c1167231d2e, 148.000.000.194
 SEP0c1167233b9f, 148.000.000.31
 CUV, 148.000.000.254
 SEP0c1167231d32, 148.000.000.34
 SEP501cbffcfa9c, 148.000.000.24
 SEP00082fb67d5f, 148.000.000.21
 SEP00082fb67701, 148.000.000.22
```

And this is exactly what I expect, but occasionally the file looks like this:

```
device_id,ip_address,serial_number
 SEP0c1167231746
, 148.000.000.32
 SEP0c1167223fa5
, 148.000.000.30
 SEP0c1167224170
, 148.000.000.30
 SEP0c1167231d2e
, 148.000.000.194
 SEP0c1167233b9f
, 148.000.000.31
 CUV
, 148.000.000.254
 SEP0c1167231d32
, 148.000.000.34
 SEP501cbffcfa9c
, 148.000.000.24
 SEP00082fb67d5f
, 148.000.000.21
 SEP00082fb67701
, 148.000.000.22
```

I tried to figure out what's going on, but it does not seem to be something regular, now I only want to handle with this, using Ghex I've identified the character that causes the problem.

[image]

Now I would like to replace all "0D" with Null and keep all "0A"

just as a note, I have tried using "dos2unix" but it didn't work.

Could you help me?

UPDATE:
 Using: sed -n -e '/,/!{N;s/\n//;}; /,/p' input

with a file like this:

```
device_id,ip_address,serial_number
 SEP0c1167231746
, 148.000.000.32
,
 SEP0c1167223fa5
, 148.000.000.30
,
 SEP0c1167224170
, 148.000.000.30
,
 SEP0c1167231d2e
, 148.000.000.194
,
 SEP0c1167233b9f
, 148.000.000.31
,
 CUV
, 148.000.000.254
,
 SEP0c1167231d32
, 148.000.000.34
,
 SEP501cbffcfa9c
, 148.000.000.24
,
 SEP00082fb67d5f
, 148.000.000.21
,
 SEP00082fb67701
, 148.000.000.22
```

I've got this output:

```
, 148.000.000.32
, 148.000.000.30
, 148.000.000.30
, 148.000.000.194
, 148.000.000.31
, 148.000.000.254
, 148.000.000.34
, 148.000.000.24
, 148.000.000.21
, 148.000.000.22
```

Comment: you say "null" but I suspect you mean "with nothing" -- so that the lines are rejoined?

Comment: That's right. I would like to delete that Hex character "0D"

Comment: You need to show your script which is causing this behavior of printing `\r` sometimes and other times `\n`. As otherwise, all fixes will be just patches without knowing for sure what's causing it,

Comment: you've changed your input format; that would require a different solution

Answer (score 2):

There may be a better `sed` option, but here's one:

```
sed -n -e '/,/!{N;s/\n//;}; /,/p' input > output
```

It says, (by default, not printing lines): if there's a comma in the line, then read the *next* line in and replace the newline. Then, if there is (now, or already) a comma in the line, print the line. It reads from `input` and writes to `output`. With some seds, you can use sed's `-i` flag to edit the file in-place.

Sample input:

```
device_id,ip_address,serial_number
 SEP0c1167231746, 148.000.000.32
 SEP0c1167223fa5, 148.000.000.30
 SEP0c1167231746
, 148.000.000.32
 SEP0c1167223fa5
, 148.000.000.30
```

Sample output:

```
device_id,ip_address,serial_number
 SEP0c1167231746, 148.000.000.32
 SEP0c1167223fa5, 148.000.000.30
 SEP0c1167231746, 148.000.000.32
 SEP0c1167223fa5, 148.000.000.30
```

Comment: Upvoted because this answers the question as originally asked.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your hexdump, it would seem that this should fix your issue:

```
tr -d '\015' < input > log
```

As the octal `\015` is the `carriage return` `^M` character.

Why `dos2unix` didn't help is coz `dos2unix` looks at the sequence `\r\n` which is not present in your case.